# PYTHON How to read txt file from folders on parent directory

Tags: python, import, exe, parent, readfile

I'm new to python, trying to learn and code at the same time, to test what i can do, I learned java, javascript, php, html, css, on my course, so I still remeber the basics.

I reached this problem and after hours i haven't found a solution that I can understand and like.

So this is my structure:
[my structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWM7M.png)

I want to read the test_input.txt inside the test_input.py, i want that because there are some strings for the user, and i want those strings to change based on the language. I though to write the .txt along side the .py file, but then everytime   a function would generate string I would need to make all the language folders again, also if needed to add another language, I also would make various folders on every  string occurency.

If possible, i want a solution that read the project inside itself to get the .txt file, because i want this project to be an .exe desktop program. Also, is pyhton good to make simple desktop apps? I'm lookin foward to learn the future languages, like I learned android in java, but I want to use kotlyn because is "better", so I cold make this project in java as a learned and did some in the past, but I want the "what will be most used on the future".

Please correct me in anything if I'm wrong, all this is more about see what I can do, and how, thanks for the help!!!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to load and read the txt file in py. If this is the case, like i understood, then perhaps you want to follow this tutorial here:
https://www.pythontutorial.net/python-basics/python-read-text-file/

Also, did you try to open/load it already? If so, did you get an error? Most of the time, it is a path problem for beginners so make sure the path is setup already.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I got this script from geeksforgeeks, it got multiple form of how to read a .txt, I am leaving you as well the documentation.

```
# Program to show various ways to read and
# write data in a file.
file1 = open("myfile.txt","w")
L = ["This is Delhi \n","This is Paris \n","This is London \n"] 
  
# \n is placed to indicate EOL (End of Line)
file1.write("Hello \n")
file1.writelines(L)
file1.close() #to change file access modes
  
file1 = open("myfile.txt","r+") 
  
print("Output of Read function is ")
print(file1.read())
print()
  
# seek(n) takes the file handle to the nth
# bite from the beginning.
file1.seek(0) 
  
print( "Output of Readline function is ")
print(file1.readline()) 
print()
  
file1.seek(0)
  
# To show difference between read and readline
print("Output of Read(9) function is ") 
print(file1.read(9))
print()
  
file1.seek(0)
  
print("Output of Readline(9) function is ") 
print(file1.readline(9))
  
file1.seek(0)
# readlines function
print("Output of Readlines function is ") 
print(file1.readlines()) 
print()
file1.close()
```

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reading-writing-text-files-python/